# Free VerilogA simulators

Tags: verilog, development-tools, simulation

There are plenty of free SPICE and Verilog simulators out there such as LTSPICE or TINA or even WinSPICE. There are also several Verilog simulators as well. However, I am looking for free VerilogA simulators. Does anyone know one?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but we've had some requests for adding Verilog-AMS (which includes Verilog-A) into CircuitLab. We've already made a significant effort to support behavioral sources in our simulator. Can you give a few examples of what kinds of systems you are looking to simulate?  Do you have existing VerilogA models?

Comment: Why is that question marked off-topic? I agree that the question is a bit broad and that there are multiple valid answers, but the answer are not opinion-based, and it is quite hard to find free and/or open-source verilog-a simulators in my experience.

Comment: typical sickening stack exchange behaviour closing a very useful question based on "Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic" what a load of rubbish electronics is all products, all simulation software how else can it be performed. Just imagine closing a math question asking for software to solve some numerical problem - are people expected to use a slide rule to do these things?

Answer (score 2):

The GPL spice simulator Ngspice has an extension called [ADMS](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/adms.html) that compiles Verilog-AMS code into C code that works with the API used by spice simulators. So you'd end up with something that could be compiled into an executable that a spice simulator (like Ngspice) could simulate.

Since Verilog-A is [apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog-A) just a subset of Verilog-AMS, this may suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

you may find what you are looking  for :

http://atelecad.free.fr/

Advance Spice  + Model Verilog A Compiler Build In
-> a lot of improve features
-> with  New advanced Verilog A features to ensure convergencies
   ( Model  Init & Limit Functions)

Schematic Capture  ( 2 versions Xlib + Motif)
Logic Simulations

etc ....

Answer (score 0):

you should try  Dolphin Integration's SMASH it is free or you should try VeriWell simulator

Comment: Did you try them? Could you give some details about your experience with these tools?

Comment: Dolphin isn't free, and Veriwell doesn't do analog. At all.